# 500 - Internal server error for ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created one test.aspx and my local machine it is working fine. Once I upload the same to server the page is not working. It's showing

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: As Kevin Won said, you have to get more specific exception.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to help you without getting more info about the IIS configuration on your local machine and the server.

However, here's a quick stab of some things you should look at:

- Check if Asp.net is installed on the server.
- Make sure your app is targeting the proper .Net version that is on the server.
- Check if all the assemblies your code is using are deployed correctly on the IIS server.
- Add some exception handling and error logging to your code.

In particular, I'd venture to make a wild guess that your page is using some code that requires the IIS7 integrated pipeline and your server is either running IIS6 or is running IIS7 in classic mode. Though this is a stab in the dark and could turn out to be completely wrong. :-)

Comment: thanks. this was an assembly problem. Thanks again for your information.

Answer (score 2):

500 server errors are as useful as saying 'something broke'. They are the result of literally any exception you code throws plus anything else IIS croaks on. From your error msg, it sounds like an IIS config issue but it could still be your code. attaching a debugger to it would eliminate that possibility.

If you haven't looked at the server event log you can see if it registered anything.

There are a number of things that you can do to try to get a better, more specific exception. One way I try to diagnose them is to connect a remote debugger so I can see what's going on. If you have access to do so, I'd go that route.

You will need admin access to the server to install the Visual Studio remote debugging client (I'm assuming this is a .net app).

Another thing that can help are try/catch blocks and logging to a file or the event log--but have have to change your app most likely to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to upload the associated .dll. Have you tried right clicking on the project and using the publish feature?

If you are using IE, then you also need to turn off the "Show friendly error messages" option in Tools - Options - Advanced settings so that you get more details.

You may also need to change the web.config file so that error message details are shown, see the *CustomErrors* tag.